# Нow to set the condition for selectOutput based on the value selected in the control radio in Simulation?

Tags: anylogic

How to link selectOutput (Main) with radio control in Simulation

My actions:
1. In Simulation, added the variable "scriptVar" 
2. Added “scriptPar” parameter to Main and linked it to radio control.
When setting the condition radio.getValue () == 0, an error occurs in selectOutput.

How is this possible to fix?

Thanks for any help and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In the condition you just have to write

```
radioButton.getValue()==0
```

Easy :)

Comment: Thank you very much! radio.getValue()==0 solved my problem I had been thinking about all day. I don't know java (

Comment: there is a new problem :(

Comment: there is a new problem :(

Comment: Felipe, my English is VERY BAD. 
I looked at your site, it is mega cool. In Russian, there is nothing like it. 
I need to learn English, Java, and then AnyLogic - this is a long way.